# Selection.InsertFile fails with "disk is full" error message

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

With c# and Interop Word I am trying to merge all the files in a specified directory into a new document.  My code loops through a list of file names and uses "InsertFile" to add each one to a Selection.

There are a lot of files, and the process is failing after a while.  The error message reads:

> The disk is full. Free some space on this drive, or save the document on another disk.
>   Try one or more of the following:
>
> - Close any unneeded documents, programs, and windows.
> - Save the document on another disk."

At the point where the InsertFile fails the selection is using about 7MB.  My disk has 300GB of free space and the machine has 32GB of RAM.

The files I am saving do not have any graphics or Math in them.

What am I doing wrong?  The exception is getting thrown on the InsertFile line inside the foreach loop (below).

The code follows in a second.  Please note that I start from a winword instance, which is a member of a class called `PrintObj`.  Also, please note that this code works fine if I use it with a small number of files, like 100-200).

```
Document mergeDoc = PrintObj.WinWord.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, 
     ref missing, ref missing);
mergeDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = globalPrintObj.WinWord.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        mergeDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin =  

PrintObj.WinWord.InchesToPoints(0.5f);

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.docx");
string[] documentsToMerge = filePaths;
Array.Sort(documentsToMerge);

// Make a Word selection object.
Selection selection = PrintObj.WinWord.Selection;

//A counter that signals that we shoudn't insert a page break at the end of 
document.
int breakStop = 0;

//Count the number of documents to insert;
int documentCount = documentsToMerge.Length;

// Loop thru each of the Word documents
foreach (string file in documentsToMerge)
{
    breakStop++;
    // Insert the files to our template
    selection.InsertFile(file, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
      ref missing);
    if (breakStop != documentCount)
    {
        selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
    }
}
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);

//Save the document
obj wordFileName = fileNameWithExtension;
mergeDoc.SaveAs2(ref wordFileName);
```

Comment: Word writes all changes to "scratch files", partly in order to maintain its Undo list. If these exceed a certain size, you can get error such as you're seeing. Two things can help, build these into your code to execute at intervals (*n* times through a loop, for example): 1) `mergedoc.UndoClear()` and `mergeDoc.Save(ref oTrue, ref missing);`

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the path with the name of the files?

sometime ago i remember got that error of Disk full for the 255 characters problem, maybe one of those files has a too longe path

https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Windows_file_paths_longer_than_255_characters

try save the files in a different directory, like C:\YourFolder

Comment: for filename length I already have a validation (not seen in snippet i above).
I tried saving to a different folder late last night and my code didn't work.  will try again.  Meanwhile i am thinking of a different solution...
I am thinking that the size of the selection object has simply gotten too big due to a memory allocation issue (that i don't know how to adjust or flush).  I am thinking of changing the selection to an end-of-current-selection (not sure how yet), and then adding my page break and appending next file, and then doing it again as loop goes on.  Will post when i know more

Comment: Try with Document.Range or Document.Content object instead of Selection. Selection is always a really bad idea and should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: LocEngineer - Thx. Still having trouble. With Document.Content.InsertFile I can add one file - and that gets replaced with the next InserFile.  I have been unable to get it to append multiple files (there are over 1000 docx files in the directory.  Appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I gave up on the MS assemblies and used the Xceed.Words.NET to solve this, which works. When using the Selection object the process always hung after about 840 insert docs (it was always the same exact number of insert docs), which was a problem because I needed to insert more than 1200 files.  The final doc currently has just over 15,706,000 characters and over 11,700 pages, and is just over 4MB.
It seems to me that this is a flaw in the Interop Word Document Class because appending documents is a pretty common use case.
((Note added a couple of weeks later - had a chance to go back and try adding a counter every time an insert is done and then

```
if (Counter % 100 == 0)
 {
    mergeDoc.UndoClear();
 }
```

This worked.  Thank you to CM who suggested it.